# How can I use VBA to add a resource to the enterprise resource pool?

Tags: ms-project

I would like to add resources to the enterprise resource pool through the use of VBA. I would like to do so with the resources originating either from a spreadsheet or individual projects. I have been able to add resources from spreadsheets to individual projects, and publish the projects to PWA, but the resources do not appear in my enterprise resource pool.

I looked around and found [Application.EnterpriseResourcesImportEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.enterpriseresourcesimportex) and [Application.ResourceMappingDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.resourcemappingdialog). But I can't really figure out about how to use them from Microsoft's documentation and I can't find anything else about their use through web searches.

Am I looking in the right direction or is there another way that will get me where I need to be with this? How can I add resources to the enterprise resource pool through the use of VBA?

Comment: Before trying to automate, have you confirmed you can do this manually by using the **Import Resources to Enterprise** command on the **Add Resources** drop-down menu of the **Resource** tab in the Ribbon?

Comment: Yes. I am definitely able to do that Rachel. I've been manually entering my missing enterprise  resources into the pool since I can't figure out how to automate their addition. I did figure out how to trigger Application.ResourceMappingDialog and that it ultimately wasn't what I was looking for . It appears to be for mapping local resources to existing enterprise resources that are already in the pool.